# Have problems with uploading files using selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, file-upload

I'm trying to upload a CSV file to this website: https://maalaei97-test3.hf.space/?__theme=light using selenium. I tried to find elements by XPath and Partial_link_text but none of them worked.

Here is the code I used:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\chromedriver.exe")
driver.implicitly_wait(0.5)
driver.maximize_window()

driver.get("https://maalaei97-test3.hf.space/?__theme=light")
#to identify element
s = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@type='file']")
#file path specified with send_keys
s.send_keys("F:/elmo sanat/thesis/design/pythonProject/df.csv")
```

And this is the error I receive:

```
Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//input[@type='file']"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wait for page to be loaded before trying uploading the file.
The best approach to do so is to use `WebDriverWait` `expected_conditions` explicit waits.
The following code worked properly for me:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")

webdriver_service = Service('C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, service=webdriver_service)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

url = "https://maalaei97-test3.hf.space/?__theme=light"
driver.get(url)
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@type='file']"))).send_keys("C:/Users/my_user/Downloads/my_file")
```

Comment: You need a Youtube channel: Professor Prophet Explains :)

Comment: Thank you @BarrythePlatipus, but I'm not a professor, just and engineer and even not of Computer Science but of Electronics :)

Comment: That's fine: 'Engineer Prophet Explains' then. You also have a working knowledge of coding applicability in real life, which eludes many a 'pure' coders nowadays.

Comment: Well, I'm working as an Automation engineer for last 7-8 years. And yes, while interviewing "senior" automation engineers I saw that at least 80% of them do not really understand many basic things they supposed to know.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to use the CSS selector instead of XPATH?

Try this:

```
s = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "css-yxxalb edgvbvh9")
```

Comment: I tried but didn't work. Here is the error: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".css-zl2jxg edgvbvh9"}

Answer (score 0):

Increase the Implicitly Wait to at least 5 or 10 seconds.

```
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
```

It uploads the file correctly.